# FME Desktop 2013 Rastermosaiker: Why do I get strange edge patterns?

Tags: fme-form

I have just mosaiked around 200 ecw tiles to a single ecw file. On inspecting the result, I see that I fme has produced a strange pattern around the edge. The Pixel values vary from R-G-B: 1 -1 -1  to 2-1-1 to 0-1-1 to 0-0-1and similar combinations very reaching over 2.

[image: Edge Pattern]

Can anyone offer an explanation and a solution so that this doesn´t happen?

Comment: I have experienced similar things when creating DEMs from LiDAR data, but only (or at least a lot more noticeable) when I also reproject my data in the same process.

Comment: On second thought, these could also appear in the borders between rasters when I mosaic them. Which is why I now combine the point clouds on not the raster files. Have you only got these patterns on the edges, or also at borders between files where they are merged?

Comment: Just the edges of the whole image.

Answer (score 1):

This blog "[Help! My ECW has speckled edges!](http://blog.hexagongeospatial.com/help-ecw-speckled-edges/)" explains the problem:

> They appear out of nowhere. They set up camp and act like they own the
>   place. How did they get there, and who invited them? I’m not talking
>   about your nosy neighbor, I’m talking about a different problem: those
>   speckled edges. Also known as transparency remnants, removing collars,
>   nodata transparency, edge patterns and I’ve even heard a customer
>   refer to it as the “cow pattern” but let’s just stick with calling it
>   the “speckled edge” for now as all GIS.SE questions here are talking
>   about the same thing.

I cannot help with solving it yet.

Comment: It's because ECW uses a wavelet to compress the data, much the same as JPG you can't go from black to white in the bordering pixel. There is some hope, ECW latest version supports a transparency channel, if you have a recent version of ERDAS then you should be able to introduce that into it using a shapefile or similar and viewing in ArcMap use Alpha channel (not set by default) as band 4. Robert, do you want instructions on how to insert such a transparency channel into an existing ECW image?